# Ask before delete vb express 2008

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've added a delete button to delete data from DataGridView and it deletes right away but I wanted to ask if you would like to delete before it deletes. How do I add this function to this button?

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Table_RKMBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.Table_RKMBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.RKM_System_dataDataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub Management_Window_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'RKM_System_dataDataSet.Table_RKM' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Table_RKMTableAdapter.Fill(Me.RKM_System_dataDataSet.Table_RKM)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Table_RKMBindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Table_RKMBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Table_RKMTableAdapter.Update(Me.RKM_System_dataDataSet.Table_RKM)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Table_RKMBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Table_RKMBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Search_Window.Show()
    Table_RKMTableAdapter.Update(Me.RKM_System_dataDataSet.Table_RKM)
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub

Private Sub Table_RKMDataGridView_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Table_RKMDataGridView.CellContentClick

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which Button performs the deletion? I would suggest in the future you assign meaningful names to your controls.

Comment: You're not adding anything to a `Button`.  All that code is part of the form.  The `Click` event handler of the `Button` is part of the form, not part of the `Button`.  Obviously it's the `RemoveCurrent` call that deletes the current row so obviously you need to prompt the user before that line and use an `If` statement to determine what the user said.  Do you really not know how to ask the user a question?  That's very elementary and something that you could easily find with a web search.

Comment: Sorry, I am using Button3

Answer (score 0):

You can use a message box:

On your Button3_Click event add the following code:

```
Dim answer as Integer
answer = MessageBox.Show("Your Message", "Your title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
If not answer = 6 then Table_RKMBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
```

That should work :)